# Number of queries I can do at the same time

Tags: database, spring, postgresql, hibernate

I have a huge number of queries to launch on postgres. They are all a simple update on a 2-3 fields object.

Is there a recomended quantity of queries i should launch at the same time? Because as of now i decided to go for 200 but i am not sure about it.

Comment: Beware of locks in any cases if you want to launch them in parallel.

Comment: 200 seem excessive.  Do you have 200 CPUs?  A RAID with 400 drives in it?

Comment: uhmm... probably i didn't explain myself correctly.
What i have is a long series (10k-100k) of queries like this:
UPDATE x where y=0

I was asking what is the best number of operation to split them. Because i could do them all at once, but the DB cannot handle it. If i do them one by one there are too many accesses to the DB